# Web application for managing general health

Tags: webapp-rec

There are quite a number of web apps for managing unwell patients (with particular emphasis
on managing chronic conditions, implants, embedded medication). I want some suggestions for a web app for people in good health, like where

- they can check their health by themselves easily
- suggestion and information about their health status are displayed to them and their family members immediately and they can share advices
- connection to pluggable medical transducers for continuous measurements of vital signals
- By feeding the vital signs measurements clinical decision support can be also obtained if required

Comment: o.O Medical information in the cloud...?

Comment: +1 nice question! did you tried http://health.discovery.com/, I'm not sure whether it meets all your criteria, checkout the tools section

Comment: @neo: yeah, but so is financial info like quickenonline....keeping ehtics aside, i want to know about web apps which enable end-users to take control of their data

Comment: [PatientsLikeMe](http://www.patientslikeme.com/)

Answer (score 0):

[CureTogether](http://www.curetogether.com/) is a website where one can enter ones symptoms and see the symptoms of other with the disease. One also enter other data.